# sfValidatorChoice not working on multiple selection element

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

sfValidatorChoice is not working on multiple select element, my code

```
$this->form=new MyTestForm();
$options_array=array("php","python","java");
$widgetSchema["my_select"] =new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices'  =>  $options_array,'multiple' => true,'expanded' => true ));
                $validatorSchema["my_select"] = new sfValidatorChoice(array("choices" =>array_keys($options_array)));
```

Note: i have also tried using array_keys and by directly passing the array to sfValidatorChoice.

when i submit, it gives me `Invalid` error(when checked) and `Required`(when unchecked).
is there any error in parameters or is bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to enable "multiple" in the validator as well as the widget:

```
"multiple" => true
```

To make having any selection optional, you need to set required to `false`:

```
"required" => false
```

Finally, I can't exactly remember how to use sfValidatorChoice (it's been a while), but I think it's best to make the values readable, so I'd do:

```
$options_array=array('php'=>'php','python'=>'python','java'=>'java');
```

I'm not certain this will fix the problem, but it may well do.

Comment: the problem was, i didnt set "multiple" => true in sfValidatorChoice, the "choices" =>$options_array. hence it was not working as desired...